# Oracle db table data loading is too slow in DBeaver

Tags: oracle, dbeaver

I'm using DBeaver to connect to an Oracle database. Database connection and table properties view functions are working fine without any delay. But fetching table data is too slow(sometimes around 50 seconds).

Any settings to speed up fetching table data in DBeaver?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Changing following settings in your oracle db connection will be faster fetching table data than it's not set.

Right click on your db connection --> Edit Connection --> Oracle properties --> tick on 'Use RULE hint for system catalog queries'
(by default this is not set)

[image]

---

**UPDATE**

In the newer version (21.0.0) of DBeaver, many more performance options appear here. Turning on them significantly improves the performance for me

[image]

Comment: What is this DBeaver version? Mine (v21.0.0) doesn't seem to have this option.

Answer (score 2):

I've never used DBeaver, but I often see applications which use too small an "array fetch size"**, which often poses fetch issues.

** Array fetch size note:
As per the Oracle documentation the Fetch Buffer Size is an application side memory setting that affects the number of rows returned by a single fetch.  Generally you balance the number of rows returned with a single fetch (a.k.a. array fetch size) with the number of rows needed to be fetched.

A low array fetch size compared to the number of rows needed to be returned will manifest as delays from increased network and client side processing needed to process each fetch (i.e. the high cost of each network round trip [SQL*Net protocol]).

If this is the case, you will likely see very high waits on “SQL*Net message from client”* [in gv$session or elsewhere].

*SQL*Net message from client
This wait event is posted by the session when it is waiting for a message from the client to arrive. Generally, this means that the session is just sitting idle, however, in a Client/Server environment it could also means that either the client process is running slow or there are network latency delays. The database performance is not degraded by high wait times for this wait event.